# How to make one turtle follow another side by side?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am just trying to make something very simple in turtle graphics, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make one turtle stay next to another turtle, when that turtle is being controlled by someone using the keyboard.

I've tried looking this up but I couldn't find any answers.
'''

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")

def bob_start():
    bob.speed(0)
    bob.penup()
    bob.hideturtle()
    bob.goto(500,0)
    bob.showturtle()

def fred_start():
    fred.speed(0)
    fred.penup()
    fred.hideturtle()
    fred.goto(-500,0)
    fred.showturtle()

#Fred
fred = turtle.Turtle()
fred.color("red")
fred.shape("square")
fred.shapesize(stretch_len=2,stretch_wid=2)
fred_start()

#Bob
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.color("blue")
bob.shape("square")
bob.shapesize(stretch_len=2,stretch_wid=2)
bob_start()

#Bob Laser
bob_laser = turtle.Turtle()
bob_laser.shape("square")
bob_laser.shapesize(stretch_len=5,stretch_wid=0.5)
bob_laser.color("yellow")
bob_laser.penup()

def fred_up():
    y = fred.ycor()
    y += 4
    fred.sety(y)
def fred_down():
    y = fred.ycor()
    y -= 4
    fred.sety(y)
def bob_up():
    y = bob.ycor()
    y += 4
    bob.sety(y)
def bob_down():
    y = bob.ycor()
    y -= 4
    bob.sety(y)

# Key Bindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(fred_up, "w")
turtle.onkeypress(fred_down, "s")
turtle.onkeypress(bob_up, "Up")
turtle.onkeypress(bob_down, "Down")


wn.exitonclick()



while bob_laser.ycor != bob.ycor:
    bob_laser.penup()
    bob_laser.hideturtle()
    bob_laser.goto(500,bob.ycor)
    bob_laser.showturtle()
```

'''

I am trying to make one turtle stay next to another turtle while that turtle is being controlled by a person.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, the answer could be as simple as:

```
 bob_laser.goto(bob.position())
```

whenever you move turtle `bob`.  Here's a rework of your code using this approach:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def turtle_start(color, x_coordinate):
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.shape('square')
    turtle.shapesize(2)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.setx(x_coordinate)
    turtle.showturtle()

    return turtle

def fred_up():
    fred.forward(4)

def fred_down():
    fred.backward(4)

def bob_up():
    screen.onkeypress(None, 'Up')  # disable complex handler inside handler
    bob.forward(4)
    bob_laser.goto(bob.position())
    screen.onkeypress(bob_up, 'Up')  # reenable handler

def bob_down():
    screen.onkeypress(None, 'Down')
    bob.backward(4)
    bob_laser.goto(bob.position())
    screen.onkeypress(bob_down, 'Down')

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1200, 600)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Fred
fred = turtle_start('red', -500)

# Bob
bob = turtle_start('blue', 500)

# Bob Laser
bob_laser = Turtle()
bob_laser.shape('square')
bob_laser.shapesize(stretch_len=5, stretch_wid=0.5)
bob_laser.color('yellow')
bob_laser.penup()

# Key Bindings
screen.onkeypress(fred_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(fred_down, 's')
screen.onkeypress(bob_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(bob_down, 'Down')
screen.listen()

screen.exitonclick()
```